# Android Studio 2.3 not showing properties window

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.3 When I click on a button or textfield or any widget I want the properties windows to show up on the right so I can see all available properties for that widget and edit the properties there. How can I get the properties window to appear?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. If you press shift+f12 it will restore the default layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me